# Turing machine that accepts $a^{n^2}$

Tags: turing-machines

How do you make a TM that accepts the following language?

$$ \{ a^{n^2} \mid n \ge 0 \} $$

Comment: Welcome to CS Stack Exchange! Look here on how to ask a good question: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We discourage posts that are just the statement of an exercise-style task.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to go about it.

The idea is to use $n^2 = 1 + 3 + \cdots + (2n-1)$.

Accordingly, we construct a Turing machine which will transform the input in the following way:

$$ a^n \to b a^{n-1} \to cb^3 a^{n-4} \to c^4 b^5 a^{n-9} \to \cdots $$

To move from $c^{m^2} b^{2m+1}$ to $c^{(m+1)^2} b^{2m+3}$, repeatedly change the leftmost $b$ to a $c$, and then the leftmost $a$ to a $d$; when running out of $b$s, change all $d$s to $b$s.

If, in the middle of the process, you run out of $a$s, then the answer is negative. If you run out of $a$s right at the beginning of a stage, the answer is positive.